# AWS CLI's call for Service Catalog's Launch Product

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, catalog

Is there any AWS CLI's call to Service Catalog's Launch Product?
I looked into "aws create-provisioning-artifact" , but not sure how to define the key-value of the parameters since the documentation only mention KeyName string but not Value string?
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/servicecatalog/create-provisioning-artifact.html)

I tried to use the format "KeyName"="Value" in Paramater's Info section (e.g. "Info": {"Subnet ID": "subnet-123456"}) but it throwed an exception:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
>   CreateProvisioningArtifact operation: 1 validation error detected:
>   Value '{SubnetID=subnet-123456}' at 'parameters.info' failed to
>   satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 1

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you define a parameter as an array you have to write like this Key=string,Value=string ... Example:

```
--tags Key=Name,Value=your_value
```